# Just update when a specific field changes

Tags: trigger

I created a trigger to open a case in my account if `(Atribuido__c == 'SIM')`

I want the trigger to fire just when this field is updated.

If this field is already updated and I update any other fields in my Account the trigger should not.

The trigger that I've done is firing always when I update my account if `(Atribuido__c == 'SIM')`

```
trigger CriarCaseAccount_AR on Account (after update) {
    List<Case> Cases = new List<Case>();
    List<Account> act = Trigger.new;

    for (Account ct : act) {
        if (ct.Antecipado__c == 'SIM' && ct.RecordTypeID == '012U00000000vYx' || ct.Antecipado__c == 'AR' && ct.RecordTypeID == '012U00000000vYx'){
            Case c = new Case(
                AccountID = ct.id,
                RecordTypeID = '012U000000011yC',
                Motivo__c = 'Formandos AR',
                Prazo_para_resolucao__c = Date.today(),
                Description = 'Montagens',
                Subject = ct.id,
                Ownerid = '005U0000001KraS'
            );

            cases.add(c);
        }
     }

     insert cases;
}
```

How I determine the trigger just fire when this specific field is updated?

Thanks Phil !

I just made some changes and works perfectly !

I was trying to fire my trigger just when "Antecipado" == 'SIM' or 'AR'.
If this field is already 'SIM' or 'AR' and I update another field in my Account.
The trigger can't be fired.

So:

```
for (Account acc: Trigger.new) {
    Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID);

    if (acc.Antecipado__c != oldAccount.Antecipado__c) {
        If (acc.Antecipado__c == 'SIM' || acc.Antecipado__c == 'AR') {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean: if the field is already updated?  I assume it's translation thing, but can you be more specific? do you want to compare to the before update? was it updated on a previous transaction?

Comment: Great, glad it worked @Everton CP7, if click on the Tick next to my answer, that marks it as answered.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For this, you can reference the Trigger.oldMap and Trigger.newMap map collections.  So, you can compare old values with new values. For example:

```
for( Id accountId : Trigger.newMap.keySet() )
{
  if( Trigger.oldMap.get( accountId ).Antecipado__c != Trigger.newMap.get( accountId ).Antecipado__c )
  {
     // do something here because your field has changed
  }
}
```

So, the Trigger will always 'fire' but you will only act upon it if the new and old values are different (i.e. if the user updated the value).

Comment: Help I have almost the same problem, however, it doesn't seem to be working for me. **trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {<br> for (Contact c : Trigger.new){<br> Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id);<br> if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c != oldContact.One_Prop_Owned__c){<br> if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c == '');<br> McLabs2__Ownership__c newOwn = new McLabs2__Ownership__c();<br> newOwn.McLabs2__Contact__c = c.id;<br> newOwn.McLabs2__Property__c = c.One_Prop_Owned__c;<br> insert newOwn;<br> }<br> }<br>

Comment: I believe you need to change `Account` to `Id` in the for loop.  At least I did.

Comment: You're right, have modified - only took 5 years for someone to notice :)