# Check whether Record Owner has changed - Loop variable must be of type Id error

Tags: apex, ownership

I need to check whether the change which has triggered my Apex code was the **Case** Owner being changed. But the below causes the following error message

> Loop variable must be of type Id

```
List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
for (Case c : Trigger.newMap.keySet()){
    if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.OwnerId) != Trigger.newMap.get(c.OwnerId))
    {
        caseIds.add(c.Id);
    }
```

and I can't work out why, since the answer on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/just-update-when-a-specific-field-changes/11192#11192/%22this%22) post does almost exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to iterate the cases from a list, like so:

```
for (Case c : Trigger.newMap.values()){
if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.OwnerId) != Trigger.newMap.get(c.OwnerId))
{
    caseIds.add(c.Id);
}
```

Note that I'm using `values()` not `keySet()`. You can iterate both, but in this instance, you want the case, so you can access it's owner id.

I was in a bit of a hurry and as noted by Ranga, Trigger.new is probably the best way to access the Trigger list.

I see what the problem is - you are attempting to access the cases in the maps via `OwnerId` - you have to use the actual case `Id` for that. Try this:

```
Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
if (oldCase != null && oldCase.OwnerId != c.OwnerId)
{
    caseIds.add(c.Id);
}
```

Comment: also we can use Trigger.new variable to loop through rather than Trigger.newMap.values()

Comment: Thanks, that's got rid of the error message. But when I change the Case Owner  the list's not being updated. I'm checking with if(caseIds.isEmpty() == false){ and else{debug which is showing up in my debug log. All I'm doing earlier in the code is creating a list of Ids from a Custom Setting but I'm not checking against it until later. Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: Can you describe the preconditions, what you are trying to achieve in the code and what you want the output to be? I'm just a little confused about your reference to the "list" - the values in the Trigger list will never change until the trigger fires again...

Comment: I want to check whether the Case Owner has been changed & that the Case Record Type is listed in a Custom Setting. If it is, I need to complete a Milestone with a particular name. Shall I update the question to include the complete code? As for my list comment - that's just my poor choice of words, as I'm new to Apex and don't fully understand the terminology. What I meant was CaseIds.isEmpty() must be evaluating to True since my debug's being triggered.

Comment: I updated the answer - I'm confident this will fix your issue.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for still trying to find a solution after I'd accepted your answer. After ~12 hours this is finally working!

Comment: Oh man, that's rough. Glad it helped. If you like, you can hit the "Accept" button and I can get my fix of worthless stackoverflow rep points ;)

Comment: Sorry, I through I had already, thanks for the heads up.