# Run Update Trigger only if a few fields are changed

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger, helper

I have Trigger and Trigger Helper. My trigger looks like that:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    TriggerHelper.updateTools(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
    TriggerHelper.updateToolsByGears(Trigger.new);  
}
```

And I need to run the `updateTools` method, only if a few fields from `Trigger.old` are changed. How can I do this correct?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/just-update-when-a-specific-field-changes

Comment: Still nothing. I don't know, how to do this. In helper I have many loops already.

Comment: The important thing is that you need to make an attempt. Try to type out (even if it's only in notepad on your local computer) things like your goal (compare fields) and the information you have that you can work with (like trigger.old). Programming is an exercise in, among other things, determining the data you need and how to get it. You've asked enough questions that I expect some knowledge retention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to compare the old values and new values see the below example :

```
for(yourObject obj : trigger.new){
     if(obj.yourfield !== Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id).yourfield)  {
      //your code
     }
}
```

while modifying your code, also think about bulkified scenarios..

In your code 
    TriggerHelper.updateTools(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
you are passing Trigger.old, Trigger.new list to the helper class functions.

So can create two lists respective of old then you can compare and add the instance of your object to the list then you can pass that list to the helper , like this:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        list<yourObject>newObjList = new list<yourObject>();
        list<yourObject>oldObjList = new list<yourObject>();
        for(yourObject obj : trigger.new){
            if(obj.yourfield !== Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id).yourfield )
            {
                newObjList.add(obj);
                oldObjList.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id))         
            }
        }
        if(newObjList.size()>0){
            TriggerHelper.updateTools(oldObjList, newObjList);
        }
        TriggerHelper.updateToolsByGears(Trigger.new);  
    }
```

if you can modify your "updateTools" method(you can pass the trigger.new and Trigger.oldMap to the helper class then you can compare old and new values from there itself  ) that will be the best way so you can keep your trigger clean

Comment: Thank you! And if we're talking about a helper's method, that have to be called after update and after insert too? I can see there only `Trigger.new` as possible List/Map.

Comment: you can move the old and new comparison to your helper class and if the value is changed then only you need to process the record: like this  TriggerHelper.updateTools(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new);  you can change your TriggerHelper class method first parameter to a Map and you can easily compare from there.